# Session Timeout in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session-timeout

I have written a page with an iFrame that basically cycles through a series of internal pages on our server displaying daily activity for our company.  The problem I think is that it sporadically loses its session and redirects back to the login screen to keep losing its session which is the default behavior for anyone on our site trying to access a webpage without being logged in.

I have set the session timeout to 4hrs, the iframe cycles through 6 pages anywhere from 10 seconds to 5 minutes on each, and I have even set the META refresh on the page to refresh every 3 hours.  I don't understand what else could possibly stop this page from staying active.

Comment: Is there any possibility to use AJAX instead of Iframe? I suspect this would be a better design solution than using an Iframe?

Comment: I started with AJAX but then found out that some users still use IE6 and without ActiveX enabled.  Ultimately, it will most likely be converted back at some point.

Comment: Since this is for an internal site, it has been pushed back in priority but I will be sure to come back, reply, and check best solution once I am able to test.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help you: [keep-session-alive](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1086/keep-session-alive/)

Comment: @Urbycoz: Thanks. I must admit that i'm not sure which link it was. Maybe this is what it originally showed: [Defibrillator: Keeping ASP.NET Session Alive Ad Infinitum](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10550/The-Defibrillator-Keeping-ASP-NET-Session-Alive-Ad) (hopefully this lives longer)

Answer (score 0):

Check the authentication cookie timeout.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms name="ApplicationLogin" loginUrl="Login.aspx" path="/" protection="All" timeout="240">
</forms>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your application pool is timing out.

> IIS takes precedence, but they deal with slightly different scenarios.
>
> In the case of IIS, the default 20 minutes time-out for the application pool is referring to incoming requests. If your application doesn't receive any requests at all for 20 minutes then the application pool is put to sleep to save resources. When this happens all the sessions in your application are gone.
>
> The ASP.NET session time-out deals with per-session requests. Your site could be quite busy, but if one user (i.e. session) is not active for 20 minutes only that session is discarded.
>
> So yes, to make sure the session stays alive for 60 minutes you have to change the time-out settings for the IIS application pool as well as web.config.

[ASP.NET 2.0 Session Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261117/asp-net-2-0-session-timeout/3261251#3261251)